# problem while processing username and email in django-rest

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am getting username and email from user but even if user sends any one of username or email then I want to pass through the check below. but right now it is working only if user sends both of the username and email.

```
    username = request.GET.get('username')
    email = request.GET.get('email')
    print(username)
    if not username or not email:
        return Response({
            'message': "username or email missing.",
        }, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `if not username and not email:`. This coundition will be `True` if both username and email are missing.